# how to add repository in php project through composer

Tags: php, json, composer-php, repository

I am new to use composer. I have installed composer globally. Now i have created compser.json file through composer.init

I have seen in somewhere if i want that class just need to put following lines in my composer.json

```
{
  "require":
  {
    "phpclasses/formsgeneration": ">=1.0.24"
  },
  "repositories":
  [
    {
      "type": "composer",
      "url": "https:\/\/www.phpclasses.org\/"
    },
    {
      "packagist": false
    }
  ]
}
```

so now i have put that line in my composer.json file but nothing happened like i didn't get any files or folder. How to get this class in my project?

Comment: Did you run ```composer install```?

Comment: No, but When i type composer-v it show version so i guess composer is installed

Comment: So I recommend you to start your journey with composer from [composer's doc](https://getcomposer.org/doc/). ```composer install``` command installs dependencies not composer itself. Dive into doc, you will know then how to play with composer.

Comment: Thank a lot.. it works